# Подскажите как прописать данную рамку, проблема с кавычками

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Не представляю как сделать данную рамку с квычками
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: желтая рамка relative, кавычки - absolute top 0 right 0 и низ.

Comment: например, картинкой. Да и вообще можно просто картинку сделать

Comment: я думал об этом, но не знаю правильно ли делать эту рамку картинкой

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так, для контейнера задать бордер, а кавычки абсолютно позиционировать в нужные края используя псевдоэлементы `before` и `after`:

```css
.border {
  border: 3px solid #FDCC37;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.border:before,
.border:after {
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  color: #FDCC37;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 1;
}
.border:before {
  content: "\201D";
  bottom: -10px;
  left: -3px;
}
.border:after {
  content: "\201C";
  top: -10px;
  right: -3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <p>Деньги на обновление гардероба не возмещаем!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если текстом - рамка `relative`, кавычки по краям. Более легкий способ - сделать кавычки картинкой, и разместить просто в верхнем слое(`z-index:`). Возможен также способ сделать все картинкой, и, не парясь, вставить ее на страницу. **Наиболее правильным и корректным будет вариант с накладыванием кавычек** - тоесть, вы просто делаете рамку у текста(скругляете края, меняете цвет, и т.д,), а кавычки делаете картинкой(либо текстом, но тогда ставите фон и рамку белым цветом) и накладываете поверх рамки.

Так что, решайтесь!)